# How many verses of Quran should be recited after al Fatihah in Jammah prayer?

Tags: salat, sunni, quran-recitation

I currently have another Muslim brother staying in my house.  We have been praying some of our Salat together at home; sometimes he leads and sometimes I do.

Sometimes when he leads Maghrib or Ishaa, he recites Ayah al Kursi (and no other Ayat) after the initial al Fatihah, then continues with Rukoo.

I have always believed that the recitation after al Fatihah, in the first two Rakat, had to be at least three Ayat for the Salah to be valid.  Am I wrong about this?

So, is his Salah valid in this case?  And is my Salah valid, when I am praying behind him?  I don't want to correct him without being very sure about it.

It's worth mentioning that my friend and I are both Sunnis.

Comment: AFAIK (had read it somewhere credible), from a sunni perspective he's doing the right thing and his and your prayers are valid.

Comment: for information only: Shia view is that it has to be a complete surah.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Tamer's answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/2081/22) on [this related question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/2079/22), the general Sunni opinion is that the three-minimum guideline is particularly for when reciting tiny *ayat*, and that a single *ayah* can be recited instead so long as it is of significant length.  It doesn't elaborate on what counts as a significant length,  but one wouldn't need to stretch when declaring *[ayat-al-kursi](http://quran.com/2/255)* to be "non-tiny".

Answer (score 0):

The right way to seek answer of such question is to look, first in Quran, and then in Sunnah of our prophet (PBUH). Since no amount has be mentioned in both sources, we are free to choose as much as we like. It can one, or more ayats, or even a surrah.

Answer (score 0):

In Hadith rasoolalla (pbuh) has explained that if you read only Fatiha in your salat, it is valid.  Therefore you should be able to read any amount of verse after Surat Fatiha (which btw is a complete Surat already) that is convenient so long as the meaning is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Its quite late to post.. I am a convert to Islam. And happened to come to this post while searching about performing prayers. All the answers seems completely logical. And one of the main reason why I converted is that islam is from God and it satisfies oneself with logic. Along with other things, we have made everything so complicated. Rules Rules & rules!! If salat was so simple why make it complicated. Ayat al kursi itself has a very high position. And the love of the person to this ayat is great.

Dont think too much, as one of my muslim friend said if you do everything by rule you make your life complicated. Make it a habbit!

Answer (score 0):

Quoting Q&A from https://islamqa.info/en/answers/97484/the-minimum-that-is-acceptable-to-recite-after-al-faatihah

**Question**
I would like to ask you about the second short soorah in the prayer. What is the minimum number of verses that it is permissible to recite?

**Answer**
Praise be to Allah.

Reciting a soorah after al-Faatihah in the first two rak‘ahs of the prayer is mustahabb (recommended), not waajib (obligatory), according to the majority of scholars.

Abu Hurayrah (may Allah be pleased with him) said: In every prayer there is recitation, so what the Prophet (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) made us hear we make you hear, and what he recited quietly we recite quietly. Whoever recites the Essence of the Book (i.e., al-Faatihah), that will suffice him, but whoever does more than that, that is better.

Narrated by al-Bukhaari (738) and Muslim (396).

An-Nawawi (may Allah have mercy on him) said: The words “Whoever recites the Essence of the Book (i.e., al-Faatihah), that will suffice him, but whoever does more than that, that is better” indicate that it is obligatory to recite al-Faatihah and that the prayer is not valid without it.

It also indicates that reciting a soorah after it is mustahabb. There is consensus on that with regard to Fajr, Jumu‘ah and the first two rak‘ahs of every prayer, and it is Sunnah according to all scholars. Al-Qaadi ‘Iyaad (may Allah have mercy on him) narrated from some of the companions of Maalik that it is obligatory to recite a soorah after al-Faatihah, but this is an odd view and is to be rejected.

End quote from Sharh Muslim (4/105).

The minimum that may be recited is one verse; Ahmad (may Allah have mercy on him) recommended that it should be a lengthy verse, such as the verse on debt (al-Baqarah 2:282) or Aayat al-Kursi (al-Baqarah 2:255).

It says in Sharh al-Muntaha (1/191): al-Qaadi (Abu Ya‘la) and others said: It is sufficient to recite one verse, except that Ahmad recommended that it should be a lengthy verse, such as the verse on debt (al-Baqarah 2:282) or Aayat al-Kursi (al-Baqarah 2:255). End quote.

If the worshipper decides to recite only one verse, it should be a verse that conveys a complete meaning or a ruling when recited on its own.

Al-Bahooti (may Allah have mercy on him) said in Kashshaaf al-Qinaa‘ (1/342): What appears to be the case is that it is not sufficient to recite a verse that does not convey a meaning or ruling when recited on its own, such as (interpretation of the meaning)

“Thumma nazara (Then he considered [again])”

[al-Muddaththir 74:21]

Or

“Mudhaammataan (Dark green [in color])”

[ar-Rahmaan 55:64].

End quote.

And Allah knows best.

Answer (score -2):

The fard in Salaat is Khyam, Surah Fatiha, Ruku, Sajda, Khaida.  That is it.  Everything else is optional.  We have made salaat very difficult.  Allah's messenger has taught us fard and basic salaat.  Even Attahiyat is not fard.  Even salaam on Allah's messenger is not fard.  You can recite various duas.  But out of love and respect of Allah's messenger, we also recite salaam on him and his family, popularly call durood e ibrahimiya. Finally, make salaat simple and simple please.

Comment: ,please provide some references.

Answer (score -3):

Very poor answes. In fact One should read as little as 3 ayatollah (complete sura like Kausar) or as many as  ayat that reveals complete sense what Allah SWT want to communicate. Syed Khursheed Zaidi

Comment: It would be more helpful if you elaborate your answer and add references. I strongly recommend you to read http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer.